# Изменение размера собственного виджета

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

У меня есть форма, на которой располагается QTabWidget, одна из вкладок отнаследована от QGraphicsView и на ней я размещаю свой собственный виджет, состоящий из QGroupBox с QVBoxLayout на котором и находятся нужные мне виджеты. Добавляется корректно, но в упор не хочет менять размер моего виджета, всегда одинаковый. Пробовал разные способы но Qt не хочет менять его размер. Помогите,  пожалуйста. Исходный код и скриншот сцены ниже

Хедер класса моего виджета

```
#ifndef CLASSGROUPWIDGET_H
#define CLASSGROUPWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QTextBrowser>
#include <QGroupBox>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QPoint>


class ClassGroupWidget : public QGroupBox
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ClassGroupWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ClassGroupWidget(QString className, QString classData);
    ~ClassGroupWidget();

private:
    QPushButton* btnOpenClass;
    QTextBrowser* txtInfoClass;
    QPushButton* btnComposeClass;
    QPushButton* btnInheritClass;

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e);

    QPoint posPrev;

};

#endif // CLASSGROUPWIDGET_H
```

Исходник виджета

```
#include "classgroupwidget.h"

ClassGroupWidget::ClassGroupWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QGroupBox(parent)
{

}

ClassGroupWidget::ClassGroupWidget(QString className, QString classData)
{
    this->resize(120, 280);
    QVBoxLayout* vblMainLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    btnOpenClass = new QPushButton(className, this);
    btnOpenClass->setGeometry(0, 0, 100, 30);
    btnComposeClass = new QPushButton("Показать композицию", this);
    btnComposeClass->setGeometry(0, 200, 100, 30);
    btnInheritClass = new QPushButton("Показать родительский класс", this);
    btnInheritClass->setGeometry(0, 240, 100, 30);
    txtInfoClass = new QTextBrowser(this);
    txtInfoClass->setText(classData);
    vblMainLayout->addWidget(btnOpenClass);
    vblMainLayout->addWidget(txtInfoClass);
    vblMainLayout->addWidget(btnComposeClass);
    vblMainLayout->addWidget(btnInheritClass);
    this->setLayout(vblMainLayout);
    this->setStyleSheet("QGroupBox {border: 3px solid red; background-color: #7FFFD4;}");

}
```

А вот и сама сцена

[image: Сцена]

Comment: QGraphicsView обязательно к использованию?

Comment: @magrif ну очень желательно

Comment: конкретно зачем?

Comment: @magrif  при попытке отнаследоваться от QGraphicsScene не могу добавить сцену в QTabWidget, если просто наследование от QWidget и добавление сцены поверх, вообще отказывается выводить на экран то, что я поместил на сцену

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем проблема решилась простым способом. Класс на котором размещается сцена отнаследовал от QWidget (было QGraphicsView), а QGraphicsView сделал полем класса, на нем разместил QGrpahicsScene и все заработало